# It has been or it is

Tags: present-tense

Someone was ill. He recovered one week ago. Now he is well. Which of the following should he say?

> i. It has been a week I am well.
>
> ii. It is a week I have been well.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is completely correct. The correct one would be,

> "It has been a week since I got well / healthy"

**EDIT:
Also, as Wendy described, "got well" would rather feel unusual, so being on the safer side:

> "It has been a week since I recovered"

Comment: See my comment to the other answer. There is nothing unusual about your original answer. You can add the other version, but what you originally stated is fine. (Although I upvoted this, I don't agree with your statement that it's unusual; it isn't.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Bella neither is correct, but disagree on the alternatives so:

> I have been better for a week.
>   I got over that a week ago.
>   It has been a week since I had that cold

I feel Bella is wrong because "got well / healthy" just isn't a natural phrase "get well" is completely common as in "get well soon" but you never "got well" you "got better" "recovered", "got over that cold/illness"

> It has been a week since I got well / healthy

---

Disclaimer Brit

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer :)

Comment: @BellaSwan I wasn't sure if it should be a comment or a new answer

Comment: *It has been X since I got well* is completely idiomatic. I have heard it (and said it) for as long as I can remember. *I got well a week ago.* *I only just got well*. There is nothing unnatural or abnormal about that at all.

Comment: @JasonBassford maybe it is regional, I did add my disclaimer